# PHP/HTML form-action attribute

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a small problem. I have one form, for search. After submitting this form is can't stay on same page.

My url:

> www.localhost/index.php?vehicletype=car

On this url, the car search is visible.

After the submit I get this:

> localhost/index.php?body_type=any&fuel_type.....

But I want this,

> www.localhost/index.php?vehicletype=car?body_type=any&fuel_type....

I tried `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` but nothing. Thanks for the help, and sorry for my English grammar!

**EDIT: The code:**

```html
<? if($_GET['vehicletype']=='car'){ ?>
<div class="search">

<form method="get" action="">
  
  ....
  <button class="btn btn-search" type="submit">Search <hr> (658 found)</button>
  </form>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: Better show the PHP code that you are using

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing following url is wrong
"www.localhost/index.php?vehicletype=car?body_type=any&fuel_type...."

after "?" it will set all argument in get method you can access that variable using $_GET['variablename']

if you want to be on same page you  can action like following way

```
<form action="#" method="GET">
```

When someone click on submit button same page will be called with form params.

You can get all form param by using $_GET method.

Method 1.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['vehicletype']) && $_GET['vehicletype'] == 'car')
{
       //write business login that you want to show once search action perform by user
}
else
{
?>

Show HTML Form here 

<?php } ?>
```

Method 2.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['vehicletype']) && $_GET['vehicletype'] == 'car')
    {
           //write business login that you want to show once search action perform by user
    }

<form action="#" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="vehicletype" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['vehicletype'])) { echo $_GET['vehicaletype']; } ?>">
</form>
```

Let me know if you have further query.